Re-center text after string substitution
What I want to do
I want to display the date (year / month) on the cover of my document in Japanese.
I have used the datetime2 package in other places in my document to print the date in English format successfully, but it seems there is no Japanese module for this package yet.
I can extract the year and month numerals using the \DTMfetchyear{today} and \DTMfetchmonth{today} commands and place the kanjis for year month around them, but this does is not quite what I want: the numbers should be full width, i.e. 
"２０２４年７月", not "2024年7月".
What I did
As a quick hack, I created my own command with package xstring to substitute the regular "half-width" numerals by their full-width Japanese counterparts.
It works great, but the resulting text gets shifted to the right as a result, instead of remaining centered. I presume this is because the half-width characters are replaced with wider ones, but I don't see how I could fix this.
Below is a sample reproducing my issue (compile with LuaLaTeX).
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{today}{2024-07-05}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\tofullwidth}[1]{
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{0}{０}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{1}{１}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{2}{２}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{3}{３}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{4}{４}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{5}{５}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{6}{６}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{7}{７}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{8}{８}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{9}{９}[\x]
    \x}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}  
        Centered text
        
        \textbf{\DTMfetchyear{today}年\DTMfetchmonth{today}月} % is centered but numerals are in half-width
        
        \textbf{\tofullwidth{\DTMfetchyear{today}年\DTMfetchmonth{today}月}} % full-width characters, but off-centered
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}

The result produced is the following:


Woild it work just to add spaces between each letter?

Unfortunately not. 0123456789 and ０１２３４５６７８９ really are different characters, with the Japanese full-width being slightly taller. This is the main reason why they are needed: the "normal" numbers are too short next to the kanjis: １年 doesn't look good, １年 works (although this may not be obvious due to the font used in the comments) ...

The real problem lies in the lots of spaces you add because you're not protecting endlines.
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{today}{2024-07-05}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\tofullwidth}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{0}{０}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{1}{１}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{2}{２}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{3}{３}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{4}{４}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{5}{５}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{6}{６}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{7}{７}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{8}{８}[\x]%
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{9}{９}[\x]%
    \x}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}  
        Centered text
        
        \textbf{\DTMfetchyear{today}年\DTMfetchmonth{today}月} % is centered but numerals are in half-width
        
        \textbf{\tofullwidth{\DTMfetchyear{today}年\DTMfetchmonth{today}月}} % full-width characters, but off-centered
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}


With a different implementation:
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{today}{2024-07-05}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\yearja}{m}
 {
  \patrick_janumber:Nn \DTMfetchyear {#1}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\monthja}{m}
 {
  \patrick_janumber:Nn \DTMfetchmonth {#1}
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\dayja}{m}
 {
  \patrick_janumber:Nn \DTMfetchday {#1}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \patrick_janumber:Nn
 {
  \tl_map_function:eN {#1{#2}} \patrick_jadigit:n
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_function:nN { e }
\cs_new:Nn \patrick_jadigit:n { \char_generate:nn { #1 + "FF10 } { 12 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

Centered text

\textbf{\yearja{today}年\monthja{today}月}

\textbf{\yearja{today}年\monthja{today}月\dayja{today}}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}



Here, I use a scope limited \bfseries, instead of a \textbf.
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage[useregional]{datetime2}
\DTMsavedate{today}{2024-07-05}

\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\tofullwidth}[1]{
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{0}{０}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{1}{１}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{2}{２}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{3}{３}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{4}{４}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{5}{５}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{6}{６}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{7}{７}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{8}{８}[\x]
    \StrSubstitute{\x}{9}{９}[\x]
    \x}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}  
        Centered text
        
        \textbf{\DTMfetchyear{today}年\DTMfetchmonth{today}月} % is centered but numerals are in half-width
        
        {\bfseries\tofullwidth{\DTMfetchyear{today}年\DTMfetchmonth{today}月}} % full-width characters, but off-centered
    \end{center}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}



This works! Thank you very much. Obviously the ideal solution would be to have a Japanese module for datetime2 but this will do just fine for the time being. Any idea as to what the underlying cause is?

This works just by pure luck, I'm afraid, as the real reason for the generated spaces hasn't been removed.
